# adb wait-for-device for multiple emulators

Tags: android, bash, android-emulator, adb

Is there a way in adb to wait for a device with a particular name/id 
I tried following so far

````
$adb wait-for-device emulator-5554
$adb wait-for-device -e emulator-5554
$adb wait-for-device - s shell emulator-5554```

but did not work
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work

```
$ adb -s emulator-5554 wait-for-any-device
```